# What is the best way to find all items are deleted / inserted from original array - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have originalArray list number (when app not change).
After do something, i have modifiedArray which some items were inserted/ deleted from originalArray.
I wrote function to find all items are deleted/ inserted from originalArray.

```
var modifiedArray = [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var insertedArray = [];
var deletedArray = [];
function work(){
        for(var i = 0 ; i< originalArray.length ; i++){
            if(modifiedArray.indexOf(originalArray[i]) == -1){
                deletedArray.push(originalArray[i]);
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0 ; i< modifiedArray.length ; i++){
            if(originalArray.indexOf(modifiedArray[i]) == -1){
                insertedArray.push(modifiedArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Is that the best way to find all items are deleted / inserted from original array ?

If anyone has other suggestion, feel free to tell us.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: "the best" was from what perspective? It works - so currently it is the best 1 of 1.

Comment: @Juhana except that OP is also looking at newly added elements.

Comment: @Roque Yes, that is what "set difference" means. All they have to do is run whatever method they choose twice with the parameters reversed (like they're doing now in their own code so I assumed that part was clear).

Comment: what about `var modifiedArray = [1], originalArray = [1,1,1];` ?

Comment: @Juhana As it is a quite expensive operation, a solution that can do both in a single shot is better.

Comment: are both arrays sorted?

Comment: can insertions only happen at the end? are the array elements unique? you must specify your problem more thoroughly

Comment: @NinaScholz I guess you can sort both array before the comparison.

Comment: i do not need sorted data, but if the data *is already sorted*, then only one loop is necessary.

Comment: @NinaScholz Actually i was trying to solve this issue with that idea, its possible and nearly done. but its not perfect O(n) .

Answer (score 1):

```js
var modifiedArray = [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function difference(a,b){
 return a.filter(function(x) { return b.indexOf(x) < 0 })
}

var insertedArray = difference(modifiedArray, originalArray);
var deletedArray = difference(originalArray, modifiedArray);

alert("Inserted: " + JSON.stringify(insertedArray));
alert("Deleted: " + JSON.stringify(deletedArray));
```

You can also use [lodash library](https://lodash.com/). It has many functions to operate with arrays/objects.

```
var modifiedArray = [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var insertedArray = _.difference(modifiedArray, originalArray);
var deletedArray = _.difference(originalArray, modifiedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and use it as remainder for the deleted items.

```js
var modifiedArray = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    insertedArray = [],
    deletedArray = [],
    hash = Object.create(null);

originalArray.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a] = {value:a};
});

insertedArray = modifiedArray.filter(function (a) {
    var r = !hash[a];
    if (hash[a]) {
        delete hash[a];
    }
    return r;
});

deletedArray = Object.keys(hash).map(function (k) { return hash[k].value; });

console.log(insertedArray);
console.log(deletedArray);
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is a lot more complex than the original code, and it won't work reliably with any other data types than numbers and strings or mixed content arrays (e.g. it thinks `["1", {foo: 2}]` and `[1, {bar: 3}]` are identical.)

Comment: sorry, i write answers to given problems, not for thing, which could be, like you state. should an answer consider more than the op has stated?

Comment: +1 for what you just said (about given problems), but I personally think it's overcomplicated and might have been rewritten better (in both of readability and optimisations (hidden classes and redundant allocations))

Comment: If an answer has a major gothca, like it works specifically only for the data types that are in the question, it's best to at least mention it in the answer. For two reasons: the code in the question is often a simplification of the actual code (although in this case the OP does say that it's an array of numbers) and more importantly, Stack Oveflow's idea is to create a knowledge database for everyone. People who come here later with the same problem don't necessarily have an array of numbers so they need to know that the solution is not universal.

Answer (score 0):

**SORRY, THIS IS A VERY COSTLY SOLUTION (THANKS zerkms FOR THE COMMENT)**

Your algorithm runs through both arrays. I think you can achieve what you want by only going through the original array:

For each item in the original array:

- If it is IN the modified array > remove it from both arrays
- If it is NOT IN the modified array > do nothing

When you're done, the modified array will contain only items which were not in the original array (inserted) and the original array will contain only items which were not in the modified array (deleted).

Comment: Your solution is even worse than `O(n^2)` from the OP, since you do additional linear array mutations.

Comment: @zerkms isn't array removal in O(n) and thereby this solution in O(n²)?

Comment: @le_m algorithmically it is still `O(n^2)` but now you mutate arrays (which is not free)